# Maintaining FAQ data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need to list down FAQ in a web page, most frequently asked question on top.
Once user select or search a question, its frequency count should be increased.

Questions,answers along with frequency count can be stored in data table or can be stored in xml/json format at server.

What is the best way of maintaining such data? is there any standard way of doing FAQ?